# Filtering a dataset by another dataset in SAS

Tags: sas

I have the following two datasets. How can I exclude those observations in `DATA1` that exist in `DATA2`

```
data DATA1;
   input Name $ 1-25;
   datalines;
Vincent, Martina   
Phillipon, Marie-Odile    
Gunter, Thomas            
Harbinger, Nicholas       
Benito, Gisela            
Rudelich, Herbert         
Sirignano, Emily          
Morrison, Michael         
;
run;

data DATA2;
   input Name $ 1-25;
   datalines;
Vincent, Martina   
Morrison, Michael         
;
run;
```

Comment: A very similar question was just asked here: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Procedures/Subtracting-two-SAS-data-sets/m-p/237476

Answer (score 2):

Classic example and often debated (which is most efficient) SQL query of the [LEFT JOIN NULL vs. NOT IN vs NOT EXISTS](https://www.google.com/#q=left+join+null+vs+not+in+vs+not+exists).

Consider the proc sql equivalent solutions:

```
proc sql;
    create table Data3 as 
         select Data1.Name 
           from Data1 
      left join Data2 on Data1.Name = Data2.Name
          where Data2.Name is null;
quit;

proc sql;
    create table Data4 as 
         select Data1.Name 
           from Data1 
          where Data1.Name 
         not in (select Data2.Name from Data2);
quit;

proc sql;
    create table Data5 as 
         select Data1.Name 
           from Data1 
          where not exists 
         (select Data2.Name from Data2
          where Data1.Name = Data2.Name);
quit;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Name 
Phillipon, Marie-Odile 
Gunter, Thomas 
Harbinger, Nicholas 
Benito, Gisela 
Rudelich, Herbert 
Sirignano, Emily
```

Comment: Why left join null when you could just (inner) join?

Comment: OP wanted to exclude Data2 values. With inner join (both sets matching) we could not filter for `where Data2.Name is null`. In other words nothing would be excluded.